# How to create log file for a launched setup.exe

Tags: installshield

I have inherited some InstallShield InstallScript projects.
I am currently using InstallShield 2009.

I cannot seem to create a log file when I run the setup.exe.
What command line options do I need to specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in InstallScript project types.  The really good logging is in MSI project types. InstallScript really only has the ability to record a response file and generate a very terse logfile as part of a silent install. (/s /f1 /f2 arguments)

[Setup.exe Command-Line Parameters](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm#Ref-Command-LineTools_3873826509_1039960)

Comment: Link seems to be broken.

Comment: I have updated link for those who cannot google it out :)

Answer (score 8):

InstallShield has a method for creating a log file for the Setup.exe and Update.exe bootstrappers. You can simply use the /debuglog parameter from the command line when you run Setup.exe. This command line parameter can be used with the Setup launcher for Basic MSI, InstallScript MSI, and Web projects.

Here it is:

```
      Setup.exe /debuglog
```

You will notice that a file called InstallShield.log has been created in the same folder as Setup.exe.

For more read >> http://www.installationdeveloper.com/686/using-log-files-in-installshield/

Comment: InstallScript projects use a different setup.exe

Comment: This does not work for InstallScript type of project. Works only for MSI and InstallScript MSI

Answer (score -1):

You can add registry settings which will tell Windows Installer to log your installation.

The registry settings you'll need are:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer]
"Logging"="voicewarmup"
"Debug"=dword:00000007
```

Once you run the installation, navigate to %temp% inside windows explorer and there will be .LOG files with a naming scheme of MSI#####.LOG.

NOTE: This should log all installations on your machine, so you may want to delete these registry settings when you're done.

Comment: InstallScript projects aren't based on Windows Installer.

Comment: Good catch. I missed that the OP is using InstallScript.